# Apply recurring RRULE on Outlook and Office365 calendar links

Tags: html, outlook, calendar, office365

I'd love some help on RRULES. I was able to modify an HTML Google Calendar link by adding an RRULE OF &recur=RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2:

**GOOGLE CALENDAR LINK W/ RRULE (THIS WORKS!)**
`<a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20210820T171500Z%2F20210820T214500Z&recur=RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2&details=Event%20description%20goes%20here%20for%20recurring%20event%21&text=Event%20Name" title="Save Event in my Calendar" >Add to Calendar</a>`

*However*, Outlook.com + Office 365's calendar links are a bit different + I can't seem to find any documentation or examples of how people have incorporated into the links. I understand I can make ICS files, but a one-click option is really important to the client.

**Outlook.com**
`<a href="https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?body=Event%20description%20goes%20here%20for%20recurring%20event%21&enddt=2021-08-20T21%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2021-08-20T17%3A15%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=Event%20Name" title="Save Event in my Calendar" >Add to Calendar</a>`

**Office 365**
`<a href="https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?body=Event%20description%20goes%20here%20for%20recurring%20event%21&enddt=2021-08-20T21%3A45%3A00%2B00%3A00&path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addevent&startdt=2021-08-20T17%3A15%3A00%2B00%3A00&subject=Event%20Name" title="Save Event in my Calendar" >Add to Calendar</a>`

Any guidance?